# Error setting newsequentialid() default in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a uniqueidentifier column in a table and it's not a key or index. I want to set the default value using NEWSEQUENTIALID(), but I get the error:

> Error validating default for column..

But if I use NEWID() no error. What's going on?

EDIT: you can just ignore the error dialog and continue.

Comment: In SQL2014, you need to use the datatype as "uniqueidentifier" in order to use the newsequentialid() method and you will not see any error messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Quoting accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837559/autoincrement-uniqueidentifier-in-c).***

> Workaround: create your table without specifying any default, and then type in this T-SQL statement in a normal query window and run it:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
>     ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SerialID DEFAULT newsequentialid() FOR SerialID
> ```

Comment: The same thing happened to me when I tried to add a 'unique key' index on an existing uniqueidentifier column that had already been populated with its default value of 'newsequentialid'.  When I saved the table, I got the same warning, but as P a u l mentioned, you can just click 'yes' to ignore the warning and the table will be saved successfully.  I can't think of a circumstance or reason why it wouldn't succeed.  It shouldn't be calling the default anyway if it's just updating a table.

Comment: I had trouble at first figuring out what to change to make it work for me. I find it is ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_COLUMN DEFAULT newsequentialid() FOR COLUMN

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in the designer that is not being fixed by microsoft.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/cad8a4d7-714f-44a2-adb0-569655ac66e6

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx
Remarks section:

... **When NEWSEQUENTIALID() is used in DEFAULT expressions, it cannot be combined with other scalar operators. For example, you cannot execute the following:**

CREATE TABLE myTable (ColumnA uniqueidentifier DEFAULT dbo.myfunction(NEWSEQUENTIALID())) 
...

Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, I am using NEWSEQUENTIALID() by itself in the default field in the table designer in sql server management studio. NEWID() works however and I just wanted to know why.

Comment: I see what you mean, I just tested that and when setting NEWSEQUENTIALID() as the default value in SSMS 2008 I get an error but following SQL "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1]([col1] [int] NOT NULL, [uuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID())) ON [PRIMARY]" executes just fine and there is no error while editing the table later on. Looks like an SSMS bug methinks.

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect.

follow the steps here :

http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/31705