# Autoincrement uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, database, uniqueidentifier, auto-increment

Basically I want to use uniqueidentifier in similar way as identity. I don't want to insert values into it, It should just insert values automatically, different value for each row.
I'm not able to set autoincrement on columns of type uniqueidentifier(the property 'autoincrement' is set to false and is not editable).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Or even better: use the `newsequentialid()` as the default for your UNIQUEIDENITIFER column. That'll give you a somewhat sequential series of GUIDs.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable   
   (SerialID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
        CONSTRAINT DF_SerialID DEFAULT newsequentialid(),
     .... (other columns)......
   )
```

Trouble is: newsequentialid is *only* available as a column default - you cannot call it as a function or anything. But that seems to fit your requirements.

**UPDATE:** there appears to be an acknowledged bug in SQL Server Management Studio that prevents specifying `newsequentialid()` as the default for a column in the interactive table designer.

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/cad8a4d7-714f-44a2-adb0-569655ac66e6

Workaround: create your table without specifying any default, and then type in this T-SQL statement in a normal query window and run it:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SerialID DEFAULT newsequentialid() FOR SerialID
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: That is not trouble at all for me. Your answer seems to be what I was looking for. I'm going to try it :)

Comment: I got "Error validating the default for Column XY". Could you please control your code(a typo?) ?

Comment: @drasto: I ran that code on SQL Server 2008 R2 before I posted it - it works. What *version* of SQL Server do you have??? I removed extra brackets around the newsequentialid() - maybe that is a problem? Is works on 2008R2 for sure

Comment: The one that is pre-installed in VS 2010 Ultimate edition. I'm not sure where I find the version of the server but I'll look for it.

Comment: @drasto: seems to be a SQL Server Management Studio bug: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/cad8a4d7-714f-44a2-adb0-569655ac66e6 - type in the statement as SQL code and run it!

Comment: I can try to ignore the error... It asks me if I want to keep the settings or cancel because of error. But I guess it will not work.

Comment: Finally I decide to use identity but I guess your solution would work.

Comment: If the unique-identity field is sequential will clustering and paging be an issue still if the field is a primary key?

Comment: @JustinT.Watts: yes - it's still less optimal than using an `INT IDENTITY` (since GUID is 16 vs 4-byte - 4x larger) but it's less worrisome than the totally random `newid()` GUID's. I still prefer `INT IDENTITY`

Comment: @marc_s I agree it is larger, I'm only wondering because we ran out of IDs with INT at work and was wondering why not just use GUID and not worry about it for 1000 years or so, lol, is there a study on how much more performant INT or BIGINT is compared to a sequential GUID?

Comment: @marc_s is this newsequentialid() method predefined in sql server? what is different if we use int and set it's autoincrement to true?

Answer (score 7):

I guess you mean in SQLServer and not C#...

Set the column as PRIMARY KEY and ROWGUID

[RowGuid http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/8867/sqlserverrowguid.png](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/8867/sqlserverrowguid.png)

Comment: just make sure **NOT** use make it the clustered index on the table!!

Comment: Why not? I'm using it on a project and works fine, everything looks normal, checked the execution plan, table ordering, everything is just normal...

Comment: GUID as clustered index are horribly bad: check out http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx - they lead to massive page and index fragmentation

Comment: @marc_s is storing it as `nvarchar(36)` better then for `CI` ?

Comment: @Zapnologica: **no!** It has the same problems: much too wide, and totally random - and in addition, it's now *variable length* - which makes it even worse!

Comment: @marc_s, I just wanted to clear up if it was the concept of using a 16byte Guid that is bad, or just the fact that it was defined as `UniqueIdentifier'

Comment: @Zapnologica: the two main problems with the GUID are **(1)** it's a rather *wide* key (16 byte vs. e.g. 4 byte for an `INT`), and **(2)** by default, GUID's are totally random, leading to massive index fragmentation

Answer (score 4):

I think

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
    SerialID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newsequentialid()
)
```

is simplier

Answer (score 3):

Use NewID() as the default value. At least this is what you would do for SQL Server.

Comment: I've tried this but it seems to generate always the same identifier (this one: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"). So when inserting the second row I get the error (tying to insert primary key that is already used)

Comment: you should set newId() directly in table definition within your database!