# Identity Specification is disabled when creating a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I created a new column and want to set it as Identity column, however in the properties the Identity Specification is disabled. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field with data type "uniqueidentifier" can not be set as a Auto Increment field.

Comment: you are correct. i need to do the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837559/autoincrement-uniqueidentifier-in-c