# How do I auto increment the primary key in a Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio database table, the datatype is declared as uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I auto increment the primary key in a Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio database table, the datatype is declared as uniqueidentifier and I could not change it to int to use Identity Specification also I could not alter table because it is connected to other table as a foreign key , I've had a look through the forum but can't see how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autoincrement uniqueidentifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837559/autoincrement-uniqueidentifier)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot 'increment' a UniqueIdentifier.
Instead you can generate new value by

```
DECLARE @GUID uniqueidentifier
SET @GUID = NEWID()
```

Use the value in @GUID variable everytime insert is done.

```
INSERT INTO tableName(primaryKeyColumn,otherColumn1,otherColumn2)
VALUES(@GUID,val1,val2)
```

See this article [**IDENTITY vs UNIQUEIDENTIFIER**](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity)

Answer (score -1):

This was the best answer for this topic...I hope it will help

[Autoincrement uniqueidentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837559/autoincrement-uniqueidentifier)

Comment: You should put such references as comments.