# Auto Increment with Numbers and Letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to auto increment with numbers and letters. It should look like this:

KH001
KH002
KH003
etc..

I've looked at a couple of articles and other Stack Overflow questions but couldn't manage to understand as SQL is my much weaker side.

I have created a column named `string` that had `varchar(50)` data type and a fixed value of `KH`.
I created a second column named `string2` that had `int` data type and auto increment by 1 that works.

Then I added the following line to my query:

```
string + string2 as <column name>
```

Received an error saying I couldn't convert 'KH' to int.

Comment: Use `CONCAT` not `+`.

Comment: Assuming you have the ability to create table in the database, you can concatenate 'KH' to an Identity column of your choice to generate these values.

Comment: `+` is fine on Sql Server, but MySql and some other databases don't like it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn plus is not fine on SQL server if one column is int and the other is varchar. This can be done with *CONCAT*

Comment: `CREATE TABLE #Dummy
(
 DummyID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
 DummyPrimaryKey AS 'KH'+'000' +CAST(DummyID AS VARCHAR(30)),
 DummyCharacter varchar(1)
 /*Insert other column as required*/
)` You can insert data directly not having to worry about adding your autoincreament column.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu. This works great and is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an auto incrementing alpha numeric primary key in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252718/create-an-auto-incrementing-alpha-numeric-primary-key-in-sql-server-management-s)

Answer (score 2):

here are 2 simple methods you can use

```
declare @string varchar(10) = 'KH'
declare @string2 int = 1

select concat(@string, @string2),
       @string + convert(varchar, @string2)
```

More info about the [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) funtion

You can also add a computed column in your table that does this for you,

```
    alter table yourtable 
    add mycolumn as concat(string, string2)
```

Read more about computed columns [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

To get zeros left of your number, you can do this

```
concat(@string, RIGHT ('00000' + Convert(nvarchar(20), @string2), 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string + cast(string2 as varchar(10)) as <column name>
```