# SQL New Column Error Because of Newsequentialid

Tags: sql-server, newsequentialid

Hi I have a really big data and it has a column as ObjectID and its default value newsequentialid(). While I am trying to create new column with a default value on that table, I got this message ' Error validating the default for column 'ObjectID''.

If I say yes to that dialog message, what can happen? I dont want to impact our existing data.

Could you please explain this situations.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015676/error-setting-newsequentialid-default-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen. This is bug in the `management studio`. We have a lot of tables in production with such columns and never encountered any problem within 6 years. We are using `Sql Server 2008 R2`.

**Click NO:**

[image]

**Click YES:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I though It will impact our indexed columns or damage our data. Thank you so much Giorgi to make me clarify.